# DomainContext not being generated in RIA Service for Silverlight 4

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I have added my domain service but when I build my web project the DomainContext never gets generated. I am new to RIA Services and trying to learn but I am really stuck.

Here is my Domain Service

```
Option Compare Binary
Option Infer On
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On


Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting
Imports System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server
Imports Wellness.BL
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel



'TODO: Create methods containing your application logic.

<EnableClientAccess()> _
Public Class EventScheduleService
    Inherits DomainService

    Public Function GetEventSchedule(ByVal ScheduleYear As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of Models.EventSchedule)
        Return DataServices.EventSchedulesDataService.GetEventSchedule(ScheduleYear)
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Did you add a RIA Services Link? [How to: Add or Remove a RIA Services Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707372(v=vs.91).aspx)

Comment: I went to my Silverlight project properties under the silverlight tab and have WCF RIA Services link set to my Wellness.Web which is the asp.net web application. This is the blog I was trying to follow...http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/11/05/silverlight-ria-services-and-your-business-objects.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Models.EventSchedule, the class that is the base for your IEnumerable, is in a library that you have referenced in the Web project but can not be referenced in the client as it is not a Silverlight library?

I think that would prevent the EventScheduleDataContext from being generated in the client.

A simple test would be to change base of the IEnumerable to a class that lives in the Web project.

Comment: I was trying to follow the example from this blog of using a normal class library since the projects are used across multiple application so I can create RIA Service Class library.  If I cant figure this out probalby have to go to using wcf services to call the data. http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/11/05/silverlight-ria-services-and-your-business-objects.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

Comment: But how about my suggestion to do a simple test?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also. My problem was that Visual Studio was set to Release mode. Setting it to Debug mode solved it.